# Topshelf - Type or namespace name Topshelf cannot be found

Tags: c#, windows, service, topshelf

I am attempting to play with Topshelf to host a Console application as a Windows Service, but I am running into problems...

I have referenced the Topshelf dll, along with the log4net dll from my Console application. However, when I compile - either with or without code that references Topshelf, the build error mentioned in the title is displayed, and then my Topshelf reference becomes invalidated (and log4net too).

I feel like I am missing something obvious - any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think its likely there's another assembly you're missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the project to target .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 4.0 Client Profile. Topshelf references System.Web for the inprocess dashboard.

Comment: Travis, I was just coming back to update my own question after I discovered this also - you hit the nail on the head. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Nuget for install topshelf on your project

[TopShelf Install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/topshelf)

on VisualStudio go to Tools/Nuget Pakage Manager/Pakage manager Console